# How to check if a values contains a value in the range of cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two tabs in excel: Usage Report and Branch Report

Usage Report Tab

| Branch(Column A) | No.of users (Column B) |
| --- | --- |
| Accounting |  |
| Training |  |
| Finance |  |

Branches Tab

| users(Column A ) | Branch(Column B ) |
| --- | --- |
| abc@gmail.com | Accounting |
| xyz@gmail.com | Accounting-123 |
| def@gmail.com | Accounting |
| def@gmail.com | Training |
| ghi@gmail.com | Training-101 |
| mno@gmail.com | Finance |

Expecting Result

| Branch(Column A) | No.of users(Column B) |
| --- | --- |
| Accounting | 3 |
| Training | 2 |
| Finance | 1 |

I want the unique count of users who have a branch as Accounting or if their branch contains the text accounting.

Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: Are you looking for a *unique* count of something? If not, your formula seems overly complicated. Also, which version of Excel do you have?

Comment: yes...I'm looking for a unique count if the cell value contains in the other sheet.
Version: Microsoft 365 MSO(16.0.13901.20366) 32-bit

Comment: If you have 365, do you have `UNIQUE` and `FILTER` functions available to you?

Comment: thank you for making it easy for me. I am able to do it using unique-filter

Comment: @Rory Do you know how to check the "contains" condition for counting unique values using Unique - Filter.

=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER('Usage Report'!A:A,'Usage Report'!C:C=A2))) 
Instead of C column values equal to A2, I want to count if any cell value in Column C contains the value in cell A2

Comment: @Cath I think you may need `ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,B1:B100))` as FILTER() function include part argument. Few more sample data will clarify your requirement with your expected output.

Comment: @Harun24HR I have updated the question with the requirements and expected output.

Comment: @Cath As per sample data and expected output it seems you need COUNTIF() with wildcard. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per sample data and expected output it seems you need `COUNTIF()` with wildcard.

```
=COUNTIF(Branches!$B$2:$B$10,A2 & "*")
```

[image]

If you need to count unique number of user of branches then use-

```
=SUM(--(UNIQUE(FILTER(Branches!$A$2:$A$10,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,Branches!$B$2:$B$10))))<>""))
```

Comment: Using COUNTIF it will count all the entries, right? Suppose I have user abc@gmail.com with Accounting as their branch two times then it will count as 2, right? But I want this to count as 1 as the user is the same abc@gmail.com.

Comment: @Cath see edited answer. Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It works. Much appreciate your help!

Comment: @Cath Glad I could help.